# delete a data from database from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
//after creating connection

$dbname = 'bca2y';//database name


$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
$table = "{$row[0]}\n";

    echo "$table<br>";
if($conn == TRUE){
    echo "connection is possible<br>";
}
$sqld = "DELETE FROM $table";
$resultd = $conn->query($sqld);
    if($resultd === TRUE){
    echo "Data deleted succesfully ";//checking if data deleted
}
else {
    echo "some error<br>";// for checking if code is not running
}


}

?>
```

**Here I am trying to find name of table and delete data from the given table**
But I think there is any syntax error in using variable as a table name.
my code has not giving any error but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your intention -- to find table(s) and delete them from the database, "DELETE FROM mes" does not accomplish this goal. In SQL, "DELETE FROM" removes *records* from the specified database. It is more common to see `DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName is 'SomeValue';` -- a deletion of some *set* of records. But `DELETE FROM TableName` is a valid SQL query -- it deletes *all* records from the table named TableName.

If you wish to delete all records from the table names retrieved from your first query, you would need to use a variable name in your delete statement rather than the static string mes.

If you want to *remove* the table (not just delete the data contained therein), use [DROP TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html).

Comment: no sir i want to delete data from the all tables present in the database . i want to use $table variable given in the code on the place of 'mes'. please help me in using a variable table in placeof 'mes'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to DELETE **all rows** in a table, you should use `TRUNCATE`.

`DELETE` will delete row per row, which might take a lot of time because a lot of stuff is done by mysql for each delete operation. `TRUNCATE` will empty your table almost instantly

Here's your script adapted to achieve what you want

```
  $dbname = 'bca2y';//database name
  $sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '".$dbname."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

  $rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  foreach($rows as $table)
  {
      $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE `".$table['TABLE_NAME']."`";
      $resultd = $conn->query($sql);

        if($resultd === TRUE){
        echo $table['TABLE_NAME']. " truncated succesfully ";//checking if data deleted
        }
        else {
            echo "some error<br>";// for checking if code is not running
        }     

  }
```

Your user should have TRUNCATE permissions of course. And THINK before executing this, it is a dangerous script if used on the wrong database.

Comment: Sir i appreciate your answer but i want a code which take table name from a database and by using a delete code and using table name as a variable and delete a data from those table.

Comment: sir i am using a XAMPP server so how can i give TRUNCATE permissions to any table????